# Import csv file from K8s pod to Postgres DB

Tags: postgresql, kubernetes, migrate, import-csv

My goal is to migrate my local csv file to a Postgres DB which exist already on azure.

My attempt so far was as follow:

In my K8S cluster I connect to the pod (spring app) which is connected with the Postgres DB on azure. I copy (Kubectl cp) the csv file to the pod folder tmp. On the pod I install the postgress sql client to connect to the DB. So far so good, now I can run psql command like \copy to migrate the csv file to the specific table, but my problem is, that the file path cannot be found. How can I access the file on the pod folder tmp?

For example:

```
\copy my_imports from "HERE PATH from POD ->/tmp/my_import.csv" csv header;
```

Is my attempt totally wrong or how can I make this happen, any ideas?

Comment: How is this related to programming? --- can you `cat /tmp/my_imports.csv` from inside the pod?

Comment: Shouldn't it be `\copy my_imports from '/tmp/my_imports.csv' csv header;`?

Comment: @Turing85 I swear that I did with '/tmp/my_imports.csv'. I try it again and now it works, haha. Thank you very much, maybe I make a mistake or something or its getting late ;).